# Aggregating columns conditionally with pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregation

I have following dataset. I want to group all variables and split the data based on the conditions below.

However, I am getting error when I tried the code below.

```
CUST_ID NAME    GENDER  AGE
id_01   MONEY   F   43
id_02   BAKER   F   32
id_03   VOICE   M   31
id_04   TIME    M   56
id_05   TIME    F   24
id_06   TALENT  F   28
id_07   ISLAND  F   21
id_08   ISLAND  F   27
id_09   TUME    F   24
id_10   TIME    F   75
id_11   SKY M   35
id_12   VOICE   M   70



    from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    df.groupBy("CUST_ID", "NAME", "GENDER", "AGE").agg(
       CUST_ID.count AS TOTAL
       SUM(WHEN ((AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 34) AND GENDER = 'M') THEN COUNT(CUST_ID) ELSE 0 END AS "M18-34")
       SUM(WHEN ((AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 34) AND GENDER = 'F') THEN COUNT(CUST_ID) ELSE 0 END AS "F18-34")
       SUM(WHEN ((AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 34 THEN COUNT(CUST_ID) ELSE 0 END AS "18-34")
       SUM(WHEN ((AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 54 THEN COUNT(CUST_ID) ELSE 0 END AS "25-54")
       SUM(WHEN ((AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 54) AND GENDER = 'F') THEN COUNT(CUST_ID) ELSE 0 END AS "F25-54")
       SUM(WHEN ((AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 54) AND GENDER = 'M') THEN COUNT(CUST_ID) ELSE 0 END AS "M25-54")   
    )
```

I would appreciate your help/suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is neither valid pyspark nor valid Spark SQL. There are so many syntax problems. I attempted to fix them below, not sure if that's what you wanted. If you have so many SQL-like statements, it's better to use Spark SQL directly rather than the pyspark API:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
result = spark.sql("""
SELECT NAME,
       COUNT(CUST_ID) AS TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ((AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 34) AND GENDER = 'M') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `M18-34`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ((AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 34) AND GENDER = 'F') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `F18-34`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 34) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `18-34`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 54) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `25-54`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ((AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 54) AND GENDER = 'F') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `F25-54`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ((AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 54) AND GENDER = 'M') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `M25-54` 
FROM df
GROUP BY NAME
""")

result.show()
+------+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------+------+
|  NAME|TOTAL|M18-34|F18-34|18-34|25-54|F25-54|M25-54|
+------+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------+------+
|ISLAND|    2|     0|     2|    2|    1|     1|     0|
| MONEY|    1|     0|     0|    0|    1|     1|     0|
|  TIME|    3|     0|     1|    1|    0|     0|     0|
| VOICE|    2|     1|     0|    1|    1|     0|     1|
|  TUME|    1|     0|     1|    1|    0|     0|     0|
| BAKER|    1|     0|     1|    1|    1|     1|     0|
|TALENT|    1|     0|     1|    1|    1|     1|     0|
|   SKY|    1|     0|     0|    0|    1|     0|     1|
+------+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------+------+
```

If you want a pyspark solution, here's an example of how to do it for the first column. You can work out the rest straightforwardly.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
result = df.groupBy('Name').agg(
    F.count('CUST_ID').alias('TOTAL'),
    F.count(F.when(F.expr("(AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 34) AND GENDER = 'M'"), 1)).alias("M18-34")
)

result.show()
+------+-----+------+
|  Name|TOTAL|M18-34|
+------+-----+------+
|ISLAND|    2|     0|
| MONEY|    1|     0|
|  TIME|    3|     0|
| VOICE|    2|     1|
|  TUME|    1|     0|
| BAKER|    1|     0|
|TALENT|    1|     0|
|   SKY|    1|     0|
+------+-----+------+
```

Comment: sorry I was translating SQL query to spark. but I want to group them as well. so I should  have sum for each name. sorry if its too much of ask how can I accomplish samehing in pyspark

Comment: one short question. can group based on multiple columns also

Comment: @JamesTaylor certainly, but in this example I think grouping by Name makes more sense than grouping by all the columns.

Comment: @ mck I tried to take fractions but its not working instead total counts :)

Comment: @ mck I mean can we divide all columns by total thats what I,m trying to achieve

Comment: @JamesTaylor you can do `SUM(...) / COUNT(CUST_ID) AS ...`